# asp.net connection pooling: automatically testing & validating connections?

Tags: asp.net, oracle, connection-pooling

I know with some connection pools, you can specify a test query the pool manager can use to validate a connection.

Is there anything similar to that for asp.net?  I'm having a problem where there's a firewall between the web app and the database, and it's closing idle connections - the result is that the user gets an "ORA-03135: connection lost contact" error.  Reloading the page is fine, but I'd like to remove that error completely.

Comment: Same problem as here: http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=1683822&#1683822 ?

Comment: Oracle specific bug from what I can gather.  I am surprised they don't have a way to heartbeat the connection.  I would think a work around would be to write a heartbeat app that handles connection pools for you (they are really easy to implement).  Definitely a hack, but it would solve your problem.

Comment: Does the .net sqlserver pool have a param to specify a query to test the connection?

Answer (score 1):

As described in Oracle [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/win.102/b14307/featConnecting.htm), there is `Validate Connection=true` setting in connection string.

"The Validate Connection attribute validates connections coming out of the pool. This attribute should be used only when absolutely necessary, because it causes a round-trip to the database to validate each connection immediately before it is provided to the application. If invalid connections are uncommon, developers can create their own event handler to retrieve and validate a new connection, rather than using the Validate Connection attribute. This generally provides better performance."

Answer (score 0):

If the latest Oracle driver hasn't fixed the problem, the ugly solution is to build a Windows Service that pings the database every X seconds. I'm not sure what X would be, I'm guessing every 30 seconds.

Comment: That wouldn't help, I'm afraid.  There's a pool of database connections, and as far as the .net pool manager knows they're all fine.  Except along comes the firewall, and says to a connection "You're not working, I'll just kill you off".  

So meanwhile the pool manager hands off the connection to the next page that asks for it, except that connection is dead.

Pinging the db wouldn't help, because Mr. Firewall is still gonna kill that idle connection.


I've seen other pool implementations that periodically test the connections, or have a param to recycle them - that's what I'd like.